# Visual Studio 2003, Macro, Process.Attach not working always

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, macros

I'm using Visual Studio 2003, and I have a macro similar to this:

```
    Dte.Debugger.DetachAll()

    For Each proc As EnvDTE.Process In DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses
        If proc.Name.IndexOf("ehexthost.exe") <> -1 Then
            proc.Attach()
        End If
    Next
```

The first time use the macro, it works fine. Each subsequent time, even after I detach from the process, the `.Attach()` doesn't seem to do anything.

The same thing happens as I step through the macro... the `proc.Attach()` gets called on the correct process, but nothing happens.

One note: when viewing the process in the Processes window, the Type column for my process shows `".NET, Win32".`

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the following before running your Macro.  It will ensure VS is attached to no process's before attaching to a new one.

```
Dte.Debugger.DetachAll()
```

Comment: No luck. Same behavior... it runs and exits.